# Logging actions to the database - schema and advice - MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, logging, schema, database-schema

I'm considering logging all site/user actions to the database and would like some input regarding this. This log would be used for various things including throttling (login attempts, etc), costumer service, general maintenance, etc.

Is this alright? I imagine it depends on the amount of traffic but would this cause any problems with the continuous inserts? (I'm thinking of using InnoDB for the FK contraints)

If not, what sort of schema would you suggest so that it is flexible enough to support varying types of actions from registered and anonymous users?

I'm thinking of something like:

```
CREATE TABLE `logs` (
 `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `action` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `value` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
 `ip` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `action` (`action`,`user_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `logs_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`action`) REFERENCES `logs_actions` (`name`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin

CREATE TABLE `logs_actions` (
 `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

Would this be a good approach?

Comment: Why InnoDB for logging? Usually MYISAM is used for logging.

Comment: @Dor Why? Don't just drop that nugget without justification. :-) Lower resource utilization with MyISAM? Would table-level locking (MyISAM) be an issue? etc. Thanks.

Comment: @Wiseguy: I've posted an answer that explains this and more...

Comment: did you get this solved? if not, you should add a comment or edit your question with more info.

Answer (score 2):

`user_id bigint(20)`, what! are you a developer at facebook? ;-) wouldn't a 4 byte int be enough? [See MySql Numeric Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html)

I'd drop the `AUTO_INCREMENT` on `logs_actions`, since you'll need to code the application to specific values, you'll need to control this value on insert.

also, consider dropping the FK (at least the cascade) if you want to reduce the overhead a little.

Answer (score 1):

- Use MyISAM tables for logging, they enable concurrent SELECT & INSERT queries - table level locking won't interfere for these types of queries.
- In MySQL, UTF-8 columns require 3 bytes per character, thus a column that will be able to hold 128 UTF-8 characters, will actually be able to store 128*3=384 bytes, which is greater than 256, thus these columns will have 2 bytes to count the number of character in the column, instead of 1 byte (which is probably what you expected).
- Use an `INT` column type for the `ip` column - will save a lot of storage and could significantly reduce retrieval time.
- Try to batch the text columns `action` & `value` into a single column (perhaps named `queryString` which represents the action & value of the user in the page)
- Having an index with this column order:

```
KEY `action` (`action`,`user_id`)
```

is **bad** and should be avoided, because that the text column appears first.

I recommend learning how to optimize schema & query for MySQL with this great book:

> High Performance MySQL: Optimi- zation, Backups, Replication, and
>   More, Second Edition, by Baron Schwartz et al. Copyright 2008 O’Reilly
>   Media, Inc., 9780596101718.

Answer (score 0):

I think MyIsam or Archive table is more suitable for logging. Because you needn't transaction or concurrent access to table.  If don't planning to delete data from table MyIsam will allow you to make concurrent insert so you can avoid block whole table.

Using foreign keys will slow insert into the table so if you decide to use innodb try to avoid this one.

Regarding table scheme:

for storing ip you should select int type and use inet_aton function. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton

Answer (score 0):

Also consider the following:

```
The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts.
TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.
```

Extracted from:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html

Review:

http://2038bug.com/

It may be necessary to use DATETIME.

Regards.